# SQL: Joins with an OR?

Tags: sql, join

I'm trying to pull data from two tables, and I've been reading up on JOINs both here and on Google, but nothing seems to be working properly.

What I need is to pull from a customer table and a customertype table. Here's the customer table layout:

```
CustomerID: int PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE
Customername: varstring
Customeraddress: varstring
Customertype: int
Customerdescription: text
```

Example:

```
CustomerID: 1
CustomernName: John Smith
Customeraddress: 1 Fake St., New York, New York, 11111
Customertype: 1
Customerdescription: Customer makes a monthly purchase of this and that.
```

Here's the customertype layout:

```
TypeID: int PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE
Typetitle: varstring
Typedescription: text
```

Example:

```
TypeID: 1
Typetitle: In good standing
Typedescription: These customers are in good standing and owe nothing.
```

The Type field in the customer table obviously should correspond with the Type field in the customertype table. So, if I need to know all John Smith's data, I want, in one query:

```
CustomerID: 1
Customername: John Smith
Customeraddress: 1 Fake St. New York, New York, 11111
Typetitle: In good standing
Customerdescription: Customer makes a monthly purchase of this and that.
```

The snag is, sometimes the Customertype is 0, which doesn't correspond to any record in the customertype table. Their type is undefined.

I've read about JOINs in various places, but I can't seem to make a query that will handle both where the CustomerID=the TypeID or where the CustomerID=0. Does anyone have any suggestions or know what the query would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT c.CustomerID, c.Customername, c.Customeraddress, t.Typetitle, c.Customerdescription  
FROM Customer c 
LEFT JOIN customertype t ON c.Customertype = t.TypeID
```

A left join will not filter out those that don't have a match in the second table. You can add in the select which ever columns you want from either table.

Comment: I'm getting an error message: `#1142 - SELECT command denied to user 'accounts'@'localhost' for table 'customertype'`. My query is this: `SELECT customer.Id, customertype.Customertype FROM customer, customertype LEFT JOIN customer.Id customertype ON customer.CustomerType = customerType.TypeID`

Comment: you are mixing 2 different syntax ways to right a query. Change "FROM customer, customertype" to  FROM customer" and left join like in my answer.

Comment: Boom! You're a genius. You spotted my error in an instant and the query works. I'll come back and let you know if I hit any snags later on, but kind forum-user, I owe you a holiday turkey. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `OR` expression in your join clause. In your case, you will need to do a left join. Something like...

```
SELECT * FROM Customer LEFT JOIN Type ON Customer.Customertype = Type.TypeID OR Customer.Customertype = 0
```

Comment: This one isn't exactly giving me what I need. I get all the customers, but for those with Customertype=0, I'm getting a duplicate of those customers where it lists them for every customertype.TypeID. For instance, a customer with Customertype=0 will be listed as customertype.TypeID 0 (in arrears), 1 (in good standing), 2 (credit amount), etc.